# Trouble installing Cutycapt on CentOS

Tags: svn, centos

I'm currently trying to install CutyCapt on my CentOS VPS. I need this for displaying screenshots of websites in a catalogue.

Regrettably there's only a Debian/Ubuntu installation guide available. It must be said, I'm no expert at Linux or command lines, but I still decided to give the installation a go...

So far I've done the following with success:

```
yum install Xvfb
yum install xorg-x11-fonts*
yum install subversion libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev
```

However, when trying to get CutyCapt from the SourceForge repository:

```
yum install https://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cutycapt
```

I get the following message:

```
No package https://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cutycapt available.
```

Is the 'missing' package a result of me using a wrong command, installing or configuring Subversion in a bad way?

If anyone has any experience in installing and setting up CutyCapt on a CentOS server, I would be grateful for a mini-guide. It seems that several people have requested it, but nothing is to be found on Google.

Answer (score 7):

This works for CentOS 5.5 64bit:

1. Add this to /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

   ```
   #ATrpms
   [atrpms]
   name= CentOS-$releasever - ATrpms
   baseurl=http://dl.atrpms.net/el$releasever-$basearch/atrpms/testing
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=http://ATrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms
   enabled=1
   ```
2. rpm --import http://packages.atrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms
3. yum install subversion qt47-devel qt47-webkit gcc-c++
4. svn co https://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cutycapt
5. cd cutycapt/CutyCapt
6. qmake
7. make

Comment: for me, this line was needed too:  yum install qt47 qt47-webkit-devel sqlite-devel sqlite

Answer (score 3):

I would also add to canavar's answer that in step 2, you should also do the following

> yum install qt47-webkit-devel sqlite

Otherwise, make in step 6 will fail because the directory `/usr/include/QtWebKit` does not exist, and/or your SQLite version is too old (needs version 3.6.20 or higher).

Answer (score 0):

- yum install https://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cutycapt [NO]

This is an svn repo. You should use an svn command to access this repository.

```
Try: svn co https://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cutycapt
```

New Qt4.4 Packages are available for CentOS (EL5 Distros) in this repo:

```
http://packages.atrpms.net/dist/el5/
```

Just install qt44* and qt44-devel* - webkit is included in the 4.4 version of Qt. (need to import signature of repo. - check the download instructions for details)