# Install CutyCapt on CentOs 6.3

Tags: centos, cutycapt

I am trying to install **[CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)** on CentOS 6.3

```
yum install Xvfb
yum install xorg-x11-fonts*
yum install subversion libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev
```

I am having problem in installing libqt4-webkit and libqt4-dev
I got this [**SO link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309446/trouble-installing-cutycapt-on-centos)
I tried out that solution but no help.
Please suggest me a way

Comment: Follow these steps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309446/trouble-installing-cutycapt-on-centos/5085307#5085307

instead of qmake, use qmake-qt47